# Increasing disk size in YugabyteDB cluster

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

We have created a universe with 5 data nodes(airgap installed) and 3 as the replication factor. Now we are planning to increase the disk size in all 5 nodes and increase the mount point space as well which is in use without any db downtime...can anyone please suggest the steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you should add new nodes with bigger disks to the cluster rather then changing disk size of the node.
You could just stop the processes, do the upgrade, bring back the processes, and wait for data movement (if any) to finish.

For a safer approach, you can make it safer by blacklisting the node (tserver and master) first to drain the node of tablet leaders.
You can refer to some commands for this here.
https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/manage/change-cluster-config/